# IF formula returns FALSE

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I am having a problem with the following formula. It works perfectly when B6= Prince Albert or Pierre Radisson, but when B6= Forestry Farm the formulas returns FALSE. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
=IF(B6="Prince Albert","11:00",IF(B6="Pierre Radisson",IF(C6=1,"9:00",IF(C6=2,"1:00",IF(C6=3,"16:30",IF(B6="Forestry Farm",IF(C6=1,"8:30",IF(C6=2,"12:30",IF(C6=3,"16:30",0)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `()` in the wrong place:

```
=IF(B6="Prince Albert","11:00",IF(B6="Pierre Radisson",IF(C6=1,"9:00",IF(C6=2,"1:00",IF(C6=3,"16:30"))),IF(B6="Forestry Farm",IF(C6=1,"8:30",IF(C6=2,"12:30",IF(C6=3,"16:30",0))),"")))
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get it to return "0" if the parameters are not met. Right not, its returning FALSE if B6=0